# OAuth: code grant, and subsequent logins

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using the OAuth code grant flow but I can't figure out the best way to handle subsequent logins by the user...

**First auth / account creation:**

1. user directed to provider, confirms account
2. redirected to callback with auth code
3. server get auth code from url param
4. server exchanges code for access token
5. access token used to get user data
6. account is created with OAuth table and access/refresh tokens stored
7. JWT made and returned to the user

If the user then clears their browser, things break down and I am not sure how to go about a second authentication...

**Second Time:**

1. user directed to provider
2. app already authorized, user directed to callback

After step 2 there is no way to tie the request to the user. If I try to use the code returned by the provider in the URL again it will fail because that code has already been used.

I suppose I could force the user to authorize again through the OAuth provider, but that is not how I see most OAuth flows work on websites. Usually, the first time requires a full check by the OAuth provider and the second time around it just works (if the app is still authorized)

How can I get past step 2 and have a way to tie the request to the user so I can look them up and issue a new JWT?

EDIT: There was an assumption in my original question that the token cannot be requested by the app without forcing the user to re-authorize the app. For unknown reasons I was getting an error that the code had already been used...

Comment: What auth provider do you use? What do you mean by "user clears their browser"? That they remove cookies and clear the session/local storage?

Comment: Yes the user clearing cookies which would delete the JWT

Comment: Using Google and WeChat

Comment: I probably don't understand the "Second time" point 2. I suppose the user is authenticated using Google/WeChat SSO cookie, without entering credentials, without the consent screen, but you should get a new unique auth code to your auth callback handler. So you should use the new code, not the one that you already used before. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hmm. That was what I thought would happen as well but Google tells me the Auth token was already used...even though the URL code  param is different every time, it tells me it has already been used...maybe something is double requesting on my system...

Comment: Are you sure the Auth code is supposed to be fresh and usable on every redirect to the callback?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about it. I tested it with Google and my own application that works very similarly to yours. I always get a new auth code that I successfully exchange for tokens.

Comment: Ok I'll take a deeper look at it. Just to double clarify...you get a new Auth code and exchange it for a new access token without forcing the user to re-authorize (click on their account and accept authorization)?

Comment: Yes, if you ask for the same scopes, the consent is not required again. If you are logged in at Google with multiple accounts, you must choose one of them, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I changed nothing in my app and it suddenly works...weird. If you want to make an answer that my original assumption was wrong I will accept it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth providers creates a new auth code after every successful authentication, no matter if the user had to provide credentials or just a single sign-on cookie. You should be able to exchange the auth code for tokens. The auth code can be used [just once](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.5), so it's good to discard it after being used.